# Add clickable link on an image

Tags: images, links

I'm trying to add an image that when clicked on directs the user to another page on my website. I don't want any visible text link, just the image.

How do I do this?

Comment: you should definitely try smth and then show us so we can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to link the image to the page in the post editor you can click on the image and then click the link icon to set the target.

You can do the same thing in HTML (in the editor in source view), in a plugin, or in a theme like this:

```html
<a href="/link/to/your/page">
  <img src="/link/to/your/image" />
</a>
```

Comment: thanks @cstrouse , this works